# PHP Manager - Downloaded file failed signature verification

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2016, web-platform-installer, php-manager

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to install PHP, including PHP manager for Windows Server 2016 via Web platform installer running as a VM under Hyper-V but am receiving an error with the installation of the PHP Manager for IIS.

---

**Error Message**

> PHP Manager for IIS
>   This product did not install successfully. Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered with

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

**Prerequisite Steps Performed**

Taking checkpoints along the way :-

1. Installed Windows Server 2016
2. Installed IIS with .net 3.5 and CGI
3. Installed Web Platform Installer 5.0
4. Applied latest windows updates
5. Turned off windows firewall
6. Turned off windows defender
7. Updated HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp MajorVersion to 8 from 10
8. Updated HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\W3SVC\Paremeters MajorVersion to 8 from 10
9. Ran Web Platform installer and under Products -> Frameworks selected PHP 7.1.7(x64) pressed ADD and then clicked Install

**Additional**

I have been trying to locate installation binaries .msi or .exe for PHP Manager 1.2 (x64). I found an x32 version but cannot install this on a x64 OS.

Almost every link for PHP Manager points to

http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/releases/

but all traffic appears to end up here

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=phpmanager

If anyone has any ideas please let me know!

Comment: Maybe it's better to post on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Lex Li  Forking the code is a good idea.. Could you provide details of some of the other approaches you mentioned please.

Comment: @MrSlim https://blog.lextudio.com/why-you-should-forget-php-manager-for-iis-953fae81b05b

Comment: I managed to grab PHP Manager 1.2 MSI from `C:\Windows\Installer` on the computer it was installed on.

Comment: There is a fairly recent update on the IIS forum which points here: https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After watching this video "How To Install PHP Manager On Windows Server 2016 And Windows 10" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-4klYZi-CM

I was able to deduce the filename of an MSI file which gave me more options to search by.

I found a GitHub site https://github.com/edgardo001/PHPManagerForIIS-Versiones which contains install files for versions

- PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x64 - IIS 7.msi
- PHPManagerForIIS-1.2.0-x86 - IIS 7.msi
- PHPManagerForIIS-1.3.0-x64 - IIS 8.msi
- PHPManagerForIIS-1.4.0-x64 - IIS 10.msi

I was able to successfully install 1.4 (x64)

Comment: Another option ---> 
https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2018/05/php-manager-150-for-iis-10

Comment: All versions (1.3 and 1.5) were coming without source code and from unknown source, so using them on your machine is at your own risk. 2.x was built up 1.2 and is released with full source code on GitHub, https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases

Answer (score 1):

Installing PHPManagerForIIS-1.3.0-x64 - IIS 8.msi as suggested by @MrSlim worked for me since i had IIS 8 running

Answer (score 0):

In File Explorer, in "View" tab is "File name extensions" checked? (this fixed it for me... my "index.php" was actually "index.php.txt" but didn't see the ".txt" until that view option on... so simple haha)